# Is there any better version control for Acumatica customization project?

Tags: acumatica

Currently, we are developing customization function in different project. And manually merge all the code into one, then publish it.

But it's lack of version control and conflict control, I just wondering is there any better way like Git for developing Acumatica customization?

Comment: why not use git itself?

Answer (score 2):

Customization project can be saved to a folder using a structure that is friendly to source control solutions like Subversion, Git or Mercurial. To export the files, open your project and from the Source Control menu select Save to Folder: [image: Source Control menu]

The folder will contain all the different elements of the customization project: [image: folder contents]

The Open Project from Folder option in the same menu allows you to load/update a project that was retrieved from source control. Acumatica blogger Sergey Marenich wrote a detailed article on that topic which you may find at http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2017/02/customization-and-source-control.html